# Convert Decimal to Integer while keeping precision

Tags: mysql

I have a column `DECIMAL(8,2)`.

I need to change the data type to `INTEGER` while keeping the precision.

I have 500K+ rows in that table.

For example:

- `124.45` should become `12445`
- `20.00` should become `2000`

It is doable while keeping the same column name?

Thank you in advance

Comment: multiply by 100...

Comment: What does `123.456` become ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can `123.456` be stored in a `DECIMAL(8,2)` column?

Comment: @BillKarwin FWIW I'm on a cell phone right now and it's past 11pm `:-)`

Comment: @DanielA.White this is not possible as 999999,99 would become 99999999,00 and not fit anymore in `DECIMAL(8,2)`, but could be a solution to change it to `DECIMAL(10,2)` before then CAST to `int`

Answer (score 1):

It is doable, but not in one statement.

```
ALTER TABLE NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestion
  ADD COLUMN new_column INT;

UPDATE NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestion
SET new_column = old_column * 100;

...do some spot checks to make sure the update succeeded as you intend...

ALTER TABLE NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestion
  DROP COLUMN old_column,
  RENAME COLUMN new_column TO old_column;
```

Obviously try this out on some scratch data first, as you would with any new code, until you are confident that it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks I initially thought of doing something similar, it just looks scary especially as I have to do it on a Production DB. Do you think it will be better to CAST to `DECIMAL(10,2)` and multiplying the value by `100`. 
`123.45` would become `12345.00` then CAST to INT which should remove the `.00` if I correct. Could this be done in one statement? Any thought on this? Thank you.

Comment: That's why I suggested to test it with scratch data, before you try it on your production data. Keep testing until you are sure the calculation is going to do it the way you intend for all values in the range of data you have. If you're doing *any* technique or tool for the first time, test, test, test.